# Windows Store template project in VS 2013 Preview missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I installed VS 2013 Preview on Windows 8 and I can't find the Windows Store template project. Where is it?

Comment: I found in the windowsstore template in \VisualStudioInstallationDirectory\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates, but when I ran the devenv command it doesn't do anything. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's one of the default templates for VS2013 Preview? If so, according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0fyc0azh.aspx), run `devenv.exe` with the `/installvstemplates` switch to reinstall it.

Windows Store templates appear under the `(Language)/Windows Store` subcategory.

The [VS2013 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y3kkate1%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) are still subject to change, but they say you should be able to find the default templates here:

> \VisualStudioInstallationDirectory\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\Language\Locale\